# pandas, excel. Поиск значений 3-х столбцов в другом столбце

Tags: python, pandas, excel, datetime, python-3.6

Здраствуйте, нужно проверить имеет ли в себе строка столбца "Summary" строки столбцов 'PS Calendar Frequency','IFS Frequency','Amos..'. В столбце "Summary" между данными могут быть другие символи, могут быть пропущенные данные, так же может отличаться последний символ столбца "IFS Frequency", тоесть вместо PM00678A- PM00678B. Буду рад любой помощи. также возможно что записи будут идти не подряд.

```
dataframe = {
'PS Calendar Frequency': ['ELEC', 'ELEC','SAFETY','SAFETY','CARGO','CARGO'], 
'IFS Frequency': ['PM00187A','PM00678A','PM00149A','PM00152f','PM05A','PM00169f'], 
'AMOS Responsible Disc.': ['Electrical','Electrical','Safety','Safety','Cargo','Cargo'], 
'Summary': ['eeELECPSSSSSSM00187BElectrical','ELECPSSM00678BElectrical','\'\'\'SAFETSSSSYPM00149A      Safety','','CARQSGOPM00155QCargo','CARGOPM00169fCargo'],
'Result':['False','TRUE','TRUE','False','TRUE','TRUE']
}
```

[image: ПРИМЕР ДАННЬІХ]

Comment: Порядок вхождений подстрок в столбце `Summary` определен? Например могут ли в этом столбце сначала встретиться подстроки из `IDS...`, потом `PS ...` и в конце `AMOS ...` пример: `"PM01434ACARGOCargo"`?

Comment: порядок определен, такой как на скриншоте, PS Calendar Frequenc+IFS Frequency+AMOS Responsible Disc.

Comment: пример данных добавил)

Comment: Проверить то не сложно на самом деле, вопрос - что делать с полученным знанием? )

Comment: добавил )))))))

Comment: Ну зачем вы в одну строку опять всё сделали, неудобно же читать )

Comment: я новичок, уже исправил

Comment: Ладно, я за вами опять поправил, чтобы красиво было

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне не удалось добиться именно такого результата, видимо, я не до конца понял принцип. Но делается это примерно таким способом:

```
import pandas as pd

dataframe = {
'PS Calendar Frequency': ['ELEC', 'ELEC','SAFETY','SAFETY','CARGO','CARGO'], 
'IFS Frequency': ['PM00187A','PM00678A','PM00149A','PM00152f','PM05A','PM00169f'], 
'AMOS Responsible Disc.': ['Electrical','Electrical','Safety','Safety','Cargo','Cargo'], 
'Summary': ['eeELECPSSSSSSM00187BElectrical','ELECPSSM00678BElectrical','\'\'\'SAFETSSSSYPM00149A      Safety','','CARQSGOPM00155QCargo','CARGOPM00169fCargo'],
'Result':['False','TRUE','TRUE','False','TRUE','TRUE']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(dataframe)

def check_df(x):
    return x['Summary'].endswith(x['AMOS Responsible Disc.']) and \
           x['PS Calendar Frequency'][:3] in x['Summary'] and \
           x['IFS Frequency'][:-1] in x['Summary']

#df['Result'] =
df.apply(check_df, axis=1)
```

Вывод:

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: все работает хорошо, спасибо

Comment: извените, но пробовал ваш ответ, это не совсем то что надо, результат совсем не той

Comment: Ну так я сразу сказал, что результат не совсем тот. Вам надо посмотреть, какие я приёмы использую - как проверить, что подстрока входит в строку, как проверить, что строка кончается определённой строкой, как взять для проверки не всю строку, а её часть - несколько первых символов или всё, кроме последнего символа. У меня там всё это есть. У вас не очень чёткие правила и как получился `Result` не совсем понятно.

Comment: возможно Ви знаете как исправить ошибку? "'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not float" Вот фрагмент кода :                                                                                                               
  dates = ["Script_data.xlsx"] 
df = pd.read_excel(dates[0], dtype=str)
def check_df(x):
    return  x['Reference'] in x['Path+PM+Tag Type']

#df['Result'] =
df.apply(check_df, axis=1)
df['aaa'] = df.apply(check_df, axis=1)
print(df)

Comment: А `x['Reference']` - число, а не строка? Ну, приведите его к строке попробуйте `str(x['Reference']) in ...`